# reading dynamic type in ReadAsAsync method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.Net web API in my MVC 4 Application to perform various operations. the problem is that my API method returns dynamic type and on the View side I am using the method `ReadAsAsync().Result`. now how can I get my API result on the View side.

My API Code is As Following:

```
public dynamic GetSum(int a,int b)
{ return a + b; }
```

and the view side code is as following:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(String.Format("/webApi/Common/GetSum?a=`{1}&b={2}", 1,1);`
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    dynamic temp = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>().Result;
    return view(temp);
}

return view();
```

please help me I am stuck in this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ExpandoObject` to get `dynamic` data

```
dynamic temp = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ExpandoObject>().Result;
```